# Can't resolve symbol 'XML_FileName'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I add a new empty activity to my android project it shows me;

> Can't resolve symbol 'activity_main2'

As you can see in the below image when adding that activity both the generated java file and XML file are there.

[image]

What's the reason-giving me such error. I have tried with different activity names but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this click on

file > invalidate and restart